# Having trouble converting Python code to Java

Tags: java, python

Anyone who knows Python and Java may be able to help me here.

I'm just trying to convert a simple program from what I know how to write in Python into Java, but I'm obviously doing something simple wrong.

Here is the python code:

```
def correct(a, b, c):
    if a + b == 6 and a**2 + b**2 + c**2 == 18:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def show(a, b, c):
    print("a is", a, "\nb is", b, "\nc is", c)

def test(a=1, b=1, c=1):
    """Find the value of c, where:
    a + b = 6 and a*a + b*b + c*c = 18
    """
    for i in range (-10, 10):
        a = i
        if correct(a, b, c):
            show(a, b, c)
            return
        for j in range(-10, 10):
            b = j
            if correct(a, b, c):
                show(a, b, c)
                return
            for k in range(-10, 10):
                c = k
                if correct(a, b, c):
                    show(a, b, c)
                    return
    print("Nothing worked...")

test()
```

Output:

```
a is 3   
b is 3   
c is 0
```

And here is my attempt at the Java version:

```
private class test {

    /* Find the value of c, where:
     * a + b = 6 AND a*a + b*b + c*c = 18
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 1;
        int b = 1;
        int c = 1;

        for(int i = -10; i == 10; i++) {
            a = i;
            if (correct(a, b, c)) {
                show(a, b, c);
            }
            for (int j = -10; j == 10; j++) {
                b = j;
                if (correct(a, b, c)) {
                    show(a, b, c);
                }
                for (int k = -10; k == 10; k++) {
                    c = k;
                    if (correct(a, b, c)) {
                        show(a, b, c);
                    }
                }
            }
            }       
        System.out.println("Nothing worked...");
        }


    public static void show(int a, int b, int c) {
        System.out.printf("a is: %s\nb is: %s\nc is: %s", a, b, c);
    }

    private static boolean correct(int a, int b, int c) {
        if (a + b == 6 && a*a + b*b + c*c == 18) {
            return true;
            }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
"Nothing worked..."
```

Could someone please kindly put me straight?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Please formulate this as a [mcve]. Explain what the code is supposed to do. Explain what you expect it to do. Explain how the code you are trying to write is failing. You are ultimately asking the community to fully troubleshoot this for you, which is an unfair ask.

Comment: How often do you think a `for(int i=-10; i == 10; i++)` loop will run?

Comment: You only need to do the check inside the innermost loop, that already covers all the combinations. You can just use `i`, `j` and `k`, and don't need `a`, `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're making good progress. One problem that jumps out is that you're thinking of the second expression in a `for` loop as "stop when this is `true`." So you're thinking:

```
for (int i = -10; i == 10; i++) {
```

will keep looping until `i == 10` is true. But in fact, it's "keep looping **while** this is true." So it will never loop, because `i` starts at `-10` and then the condition `i == 10` is checked, found to be `false`, and the loop never runs.

So we want to formulate that condition differently:

```
for (int i = -10; i < 10; i++) {
// ---------------^^^^^^
```

Now it runs while `i < 10`. When `i` is `10`, it stops, because `i < 10` is no longer true.

This is true of your other loops as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. Much appreciated. The learning continues.